# Using OpenGL for displaying a 2D map or not? (Android 3.0 SDK)

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-3.0-honeycomb

I want to create a simulation game and a main component of this simulation will be a 2D map (topographical/navigation map), which shall have different layers (objects are moving on the map, using of labels, you get it)

The question for me is now, shall I use OpenGL to accomplish this or is that not necessary? I have no special requirements apart of that the scrolling and zooming shall be smooth. The target platform are only Android tablets (so Android OS 3.0+).

Edit: To precise my question:

- platform independence is not important for me
- I'd like to go with the easiest way concerning implementation efforts

Comment: If nothing else OpenGL is portable and standard. The corresponding 2-D API is Android specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If and only if you're really targeting Honeycomb specifically, then don't bother with OpenGL... and I say that as a reasonably experienced OpenGL programmer who's done some cool things with it on Android.

My reasoning is that, starting with Honeycomb, the normal `Canvas`-based APIs are hardware-accelerated too. Typically the only real reason for using OpenGL was greatly increaased performance, but that is no longer the case.

Or so the theory goes... I've yet to see actual Honeycomb hardware and run comparative tests. What I do know is that the Honeycomb emulator shows triangular tearing everywhere, strongly suggesting the whole desktop is now going through the GL pipeline.

Comment: I would totally love to see some comparisons too but I think that for now I will stick with just using Canvas to get me into the program and then maybe switch to OpenGL if I need it. Thanks for the good answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have solid experience with OpenGL go with it. If not try some performance tests before you really decide if you invest time to learn it or if you use the good old simple 2D canvas drawing...

Comment: No, I have no experience with OpenGL at all...Your proposal was also what I've considered. Only if the guys here say, there is no chance to use the 2D canvas drawing at all for my usecase, I'd go for OpenGL.

Comment: Good coded 2D can get high frames on android. the learning of opengl should not be underestimated. So basically your decision should be based on the time you have (like pedro said)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on OpenGL + android (or any other mobile devices), but I think you will get better results (more FPSs, better drawing and animation options, etc) using OpenGL.

If you're used to non-OpenGL android development and are new to OpenGL it would be easier develop the game without using OpenGL. But before you choose this option, be aware that it should be a better option to use OpenGL if you aim to achieve beautiful/good performance graphics!

**In short, if you master "regular" android development and prefer to build something good enough in a short time, stay "regular". Otherwise, I advice you to go for OpenGL.**